# Jenkins distributed builds

Tags: build, jenkins

I need information regarding distributed build with Jenkins. The distribution i need is not the normal Jenkins distributed build (Master/slave config) where it acts like a load balancer so that the job will get executed on the available node.

For cpp projects , there are tools like distcc,netcc etc to distribute build across several machines on network so that the compilation will be fast. Is there any similar tools or way that we can use  inorder to reduce the build timing?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is not a compiler - it is merely a coordinator for software build activities.

There is nothing stopping you from using [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) or similar in a build script that Jenkins starts, and the compiler nodes does not need to be aware of the fact that Jenkins started it.

If you have a distributed compiler and can make use of it from your command prompt, it can be called from a Jenkins job as well.

Comment: I need a tool or something like that which will reduce my build time..for java projects (in jenkins
other than master/slave technology)